# Django admin not being updated by custom method

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a meta-model that stores website information.

Model Code

```
class MetaModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    students = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    instructors = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    courses = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    transactions = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cashins = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cashouts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

There are some other models like Students, Instructors, Transactions etc.
So I am using a custom method that will update meta info automatically

```
def update_meta(self):
    self.students = StudentModel.objects.count()
    self.instructors = InstructorModel.objects.count()
    self.courses = CourseModel.objects.count()
    self.transactions = CourseModel.objects.count()
    self.cashins = CashinModel.objects.count()
    self.cashouts = CashoutModel.objects.count()
```

The index view looks somewhat like this

```
def index(request):
    f = MetaModel.objects.first()
    f.update_meta()
    return render(request, "app/index.html", {'meta':f})
```

The index page gets updated everytime and shows me the info correctly. But when I go to the django admin page, the data are not updated. [Image attached for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxopq.png)
How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to call the `save()` method, ie, `f.save()` after `f.update_meta()`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu It worked, thank you